# What exactly happens in the first microsecond when booting up on a modern computer?

Tags: boot, bios, machine-code, motherboard

There’s been plenty of questions and answers here and elsewhere on the general bootup sequence and logical design. However I am having trouble understanding what actually happens at the very beginning on the fundamental level.

For example a common way of describing the first step is “Once the motherboard is powered up it initializes its own firmware - the chipset and other tidbits - and tries to get the CPU running.” from: https://manybutfinite.com/post/how-computers-boot-up/

The key question lies within that “it initializes”. The precise nature of the “it” and what “initializes” entails is not clear at all.

(I’m not quite sure either when the firmware can be considered to have ‘initiated’)

The first couple of nanoseconds I can understand for the “power switch” to open then another few nanoseconds to allow for power to cross the distance to wherever the “initializing” circuity is on the motherboard. And then presumably some sequence of electrical impulses starts, and then ??? and then machine code execution starts.

And that is about as far as I’ve figured out.

What then happens in the remaining time for the “initialization” to happen?

Answer (score 1):

When the motherboard is powered on, not only CPU but all other chips and devices (memory, timer, controllers of interrupts, DMA, video, disks etc.) are put into well-defined state.

I guess this is the *initialization of firmware* which Gustavo Duarte talks about. Actually **firmware is a program** hardwired in ROM, it doesn't initialize. BIOS memory variables at lower addresses in RAM will be initialized later by CPU executing **Power-On-Self-Test** and other chores.

For more details see
[Booting at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting),
[How Does an Intel Processor Boot?](https://binarydebt.wordpress.com/2018/10/06/how-does-an-x86-processor-boot/),
[Booting an Intel System Architecture](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/295010710_Booting_an_Intel_System_Architecture).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the firmware program, wherever it’s hardwired, starts executing the moment it receives power flow without the input of any switches? (other than the power circuity of course)

Comment: @MichaelZ Yes, the power switch controls the flow of electricity to both CPU and the chip with firmware burnt in ROM.  Assuming it is PC with x86 architecture,  CPU starts in real mode and its registers are set at `CS=F000h` and `IP=FFF0h`, as the 2nd link explains. CPU executes the first instructions of boot sequence at this address.

Comment: I get that portion of the sequence, it’s what happens immediately prior to the execution of the first instruction that I am still unsure about. How exactly does the CPU go from being energized, after the first few nanoseconds, to ‘executing’ anything? There’s a couple hundred nanoseconds inbetween that’s left unexplained on all the sources I’ve seen.

Comment: @MichaelZ One CPU pin is called RESET. Motherboard activates this signal during powering (or when the RESET button is being pressed) until electricity has enough time to flood all CPU's inner circuits. Only then is RESET slowly deactivated (I think the deactivation is delayed by a capacitor) and CPU's microcode loads registers with initial values. Details are mystery for me; perhaps it's a manufacturer's trade secret?

Comment: Thanks, that’s the clearest explanation I’ve seen so far! Yes, it seems likely now that how exactly the “CPU microcode loads registers with initial values” is proprietary, at least in modern designs. Perhaps someone would know for an older model....